How to get amount transaction from getTransaction
How to get inputs, outputs amounts from rpc getTransaction
Because each transaction returns different data and structure

If you are doing simple lamport transfers, then you can easily calculate the account lamports change by reading the account post and pre balances.
async function getTxDetails() {
    const tx =
        "5WEJZiSc4rMn7VLuEGk2WE1sMoYAzXNdXLJaLgsDhfsBbD7PjEMwfPh1yPUgd8EEA36KuicbfbAmuVnSH8PrTeKe";
    const resp = await connection.getTransaction(tx, {
        commitment: "finalized",
        maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
    });

    if (resp?.meta) {
        const balanceChange =
            resp?.meta?.postBalances[1] - resp?.meta?.preBalances[1];

        console.log("balance change in lamports", balanceChange);
    }

    console.log(resp);
}

If your tx involves more complex operations with both tokens and lamport change, you'll need to write the parsing logic for this yourself.
You can also try out the Helius' enriched tx API, https://docs.helius.dev/solana-apis/enhanced-transactions-api/parsed-transaction-history
